# Deploying Python ML model to NodeJS web app

Tags: python, node.js, machine-learning

I trained a ML learning model using Python (sk-learn) that I want to host on the web so users can get predictions based on their input. So far, I managed to deploy it using Heroku in a simple NodeJS / Express web app. I am using a ChildProcess to trigger the Python process from Node. However, this is working rather slow (~5 seconds). I assume this is because the models have to be loaded again and again on every request.

Is there anything I can do to improve this set-up while keeping Node in the stack?

Or is it necessary to switch to something like Flask so everything is in Python and the models can just be loaded on start-up? (Which is what is advised here: [Sklearn Model (Python) with NodeJS (Express): how to connect both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610590/sklearn-model-python-with-nodejs-express-how-to-connect-both))

**Update**
I switched to Flask which on the one hand solves the issue of reloading, but it also brought to light that my models (Random Forest) require too much memory to run comfortably on Heroku. Which is a new issue.

Comment: Hi Marijndew, may I know if you deploy this application online? if yes, what are the hosting service provider you use? I keen to learn from here

Comment: I deployed it using Heroku which also takes care of the hosting.

Comment: Thanks for update on switching to Flask. What did you do with memory issue with Heroku? Upgraded or switched different ML friendly hosting?